# How to turn on android mass storage mode programmatically

Tags: android, android-sdcard

When android is connected to pc, it enters mass storage mode. I want to to retain the mass storage mode even if pc is turned off.

How can I do that, nothing I could find from a lot of search from google.

**Update:** When I restart my pc, the android is disconnected from pc, and mass storage mode is switched off. I want to do somethings with android sd card at os startup.

Comment: Can we get a little context? Why do you want to retain mass storage mode?

Comment: @toadzky I have updated my question. Please have a look